# FParsec - Collect list of tuples

Tags: parsing, f#, fparsec

I use FParsec and I need to parse expressions like `a and b or c` and my AST node for these expressions looks like

```
type Expression = Expression of Operator seq * Value seq
```

So basically I do not care where the operators are, I just care which values and operators are in the expression.

I think I need the parser to accepts input of the EBNF form `value (op value)+` and tried using `many1`:

```
let expression =
    value .>>. (many1 (operator .>>. value))
```

But this results in a parser of the type `Parser<Value * (Operator * Value) list>`, but I want a parser of the type `Parser<Value list * Operator list>`.

Do I need to manually convert the resulting parser into the form I need or is there already a build-in parser or function for this? 
I also looked at `chainl1` as it seems to do pretty much what I want, but I don't understand how to use it.

Comment: Given your slightly-strange requirements, I think your `many1`-based solution is the best you'll get, and you'll just need to transform the result after parsing. But some questions you should probably consider: What is the precedence of your operators? Does `and` have higher precedence than `or`? If so, wouldn't it be better to do a more conventional parsing setup with `andExpr` and `orExpr` and so on?

Comment: Why not parse the sequence with `sepBy1` and then convert the result into the desired form with `|>>` ?